# React-Native app stuck asking for permissions

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to install and test a React-Native app on my phone. Once I run `react-native run-android` the app builds and is installed on the device. However, running the app just takes me to a screen that asks for permission to draw over other apps. This permission is already enabled, but even when I disable and enable it, the screen stays stuck and I have no way to access my app. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I granted permissions but it would just open the `Draw over other apps` screen over and over again. Just rebooting my device solved it for me :/